# Microsoft graph API Java HTTP client does not allow updating by patch

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there an alternative way to updating a listitem without using the PATCH method or the base SDKs (since i'm doing through a HTTP client).

```
public Boolean updateItem(Item i) {
        if(i.getId() != null) {
            String URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/"+siteId+"/lists/"+listId+"/items/"+i.getId()+"";

            try {
                URL url = new URL(URL);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
                http.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=none");
                http.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+getAuth());
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setDoInput(true);

                send(http.getOutputStream(), i.toJson());

                http.connect();
                if(http.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    String content = read(http.getInputStream());
                    System.out.println(content);
                    return true;

                }else {
                    String errorContent = read(http.getErrorStream());
                    System.out.println("UPDATE ITEM ERROR:"+errorContent);
                }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("UPDATE ITEM (IOException):"+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The getAuth() returns a valid access token.

I have attempted this:

```
http.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
```

However Microsoft seems to only recognise it as POST

Comment: There should be nothing to stop you from doing a PATCH for updating a list item.  That is the documented method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http   Is there a reason that you don't want to use the SDKs for this request?

Comment: @DarrelMiller The main reason I couldn't do the patch method was because the class HttpURLConnection doesn't allow patch methods. In addition I am technically using the sdks to get the api token however for some reason the sdk documentation isn't very good and changing my project to reflect that is infuriating. Please check out the answer below as I solved myself.

Comment: Happy to hear you solved the issue.  The poorly documented SDKs is largely my fault.  I'm working on it.  Hopefully the SDK based snippets we now have in the reference documentation will make it easier in the future  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java

Comment: @DarrelMiller The snippets were the most useful part! However authentication seems bit confusing even with the snippets in your github displaying the different authentication and for some reason the latest jar had some of the key classes missing for it (however I don't know if there is any differences between the docs and the latest jar). Thank you for documenting Graph API!

Comment: Unfortunately the Auth Provider is currently in a separate package here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth  We are waiting for MSAL for Java to reach GA and then we are going to merge it into our core SDK package so it will be easier to install.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I had graph, graph-core and auth installed and it still has missing classes

Comment: Thank you.  I will follow up and find out what the problem is and get it fixed.

Comment: @DarrelMiller The Java snippet for updating the List Item has invalid code. It is trying to use instance variables that just don't exist. FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
fieldValueSet.Color = "Fuchsia";
fieldValueSet.Quantity = 934;

You just can't do that in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used Apaches HTTP Client to do the patch method (org.apache.http.client.methods.*).